# Jquery Mobile listview show last added item first

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

I am using a listview to display an rss feed type feed, I add an item on click to an arraylist, and loop through that arraylist to dynamically create a listview.

I would like to achieve an rss feed style with the most recent item on top, and keep appending elements,to it. is this possible with the jQueryMobile listview widget?

Comment: Just [prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) the item instead of appending it and then [refresh](http://api.jquerymobile.com/listview/#method-refresh) the listview.

Comment: @Jack thanks! That was easy :) sorted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily accomplish what you want by [prepending](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) items to your `listview` instead of appending them and then calling the listview's [refresh](http://api.jquerymobile.com/listview/#method-refresh) method.

For example

```
  $('#myList').prepend($('<li>' + item + '</li>')).listview('refresh');
```

Here's an example [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/otubil/1/)

If you need to resort your listview at some point you can [detach](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) (so you don't lose any attached events) all the items in the listview and then reattach them based on whatever sort order you need.

For example

```
var $myList = $('#myLis');
$myList.find('li').detach();

var len = myList.length;
while (len--) {
  var item = myList[len];
   $myList.prepend($('<li>' + item + '</li>'));
}
$myList.listview('refresh');
```